# New Angular 16 project with Material misses button captions

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a new Angular 16 project and added Material to practice and try some ideas (I have to use it for work). I started with a simple page, only containing a few buttons, using exactly the same code as the examples on the Material page:
https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview

My project is on Github but it does not run on STackblitz due to some issue with the theme:
Import error, can't find file:
/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css

(This error is unrelated to my styling question, the code does run on my local machine).
https://stackblitz.com/github/Drsklaus/AngularMaterialSolutions

As visible on the screenshot, the button captions are invisible and also there is no space between them, while they are looking fine on the example page at the link above.

I have the feeling that the style:

```
.example-button-row .mat-mdc-button-base {
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 0;
}
```

is not picked up, this could explain the margin issue, but not the missing captions.
So I am a bit baffled about this, any hints are welcome!

[image]

I also tried to import MatCommonModule and BrowserAnimationsModule to see whether it makes a difference but it does not.
When I compare the generated HTML and CSS for my project and the Material example page I see some noticeable differences: the  tags with the caption are missing from my project. See screenshots below:

[image: MAterial homepage:]

[image: My project:]

Comment: Try a fresh npm install, or even try yarn or other... if it does not fix, we can try hunt other things...

Comment: Thanks, I emptied node_modules and removed pacakgelock and did a fresh npm install and a hard browser refresh but no change unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your browser console, you will see a couple of errors logged:

```
main.ts:6 ERROR Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatDateFnsModule, MatLuxonDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.
    at createMissingDateImplError (datepicker.mjs:31:12)
    at new MatDatepickerInputBase (datepicker.mjs:3046:23)
    at new MatDatepickerInput (datepicker.mjs:3279:9)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.MatDatepickerInput_Factory [as factory] (datepicker.mjs:3339:23)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:4862:44)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:12629:27)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:12045:5)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:16336:9)
    at Module.ɵɵelement (core.mjs:16394:5)
    at ExamplesComponent_Template (examples.component.html:135:5)

main.ts:7 Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatDateFnsModule, MatLuxonDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.
    at createMissingDateImplError (datepicker.mjs:31:12)
    at new MatDatepickerInputBase (datepicker.mjs:3046:23)
    at new MatDatepickerInput (datepicker.mjs:3279:9)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.MatDatepickerInput_Factory [as factory] (datepicker.mjs:3339:23)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:4862:44)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:12629:27)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:12045:5)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:16336:9)
    at Module.ɵɵelement (core.mjs:16394:5)
    at ExamplesComponent_Template (examples.component.html:135:5)
```

You need to import these modules in your `AppModule`:

```js
// app.module.ts
... // other imports here
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ExamplesComponent],
  imports: [
    ... // other imports here
    MatNativeDateModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You are completely right, this solved the issue! Still strange because I do not use any datepicker here. Actually I build my one dateAdapter based on the js Joda LocalDate class and want to test it in my project. Still don't undertsand why I missed that error in the console!

Comment: There is one being used in the template of the `ExamplesComponent`, line 133-139

Comment: Yes I just noticed it too... thx!